# Open JDK 7 and Oracle JDK 7 Soap client

Tags: soap, cxf, java

I developed a java soap client using cxf. this application works fine on mac where i run it  with its included jdk v6. The service i create, for example uploads images to a magento installation but here I shall introduce the problem.

In Apache Cxf I turned of chunking to avoid "crippled" xml requests. 
Now I experienced that this my client-app won't run on linux distributions like ubuntu, because  of the open jdk. I tested this on my mac by installing openjdk 7 and oracle jdk 7 and the same error appeared.

Still, I turned of chunking the request from the client gets sliced somewhere and the upload therefore fails.

I read this could be an issue with openjdk and some xml-libs, but i can't find any really precise or even helpful information about this topic.

Maybe someone of you might help me out.

Thanks in advance.

This is the request and the response:

```
ID: 5
Address: http://dev.magento.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*],
SOAPAction=[""]}
Messages: Outbound Message (saved to tmp file):
Filename:
/var/folders/z6/91v2ntss00s1786v_1_5y2540000gn/T/cxf-tmp-636617/cos5007091721474555391tmp
(message truncated to 102400 bytes)

Payload:

    
        
            552f069112dde557bc577735fc4eb8bf
            5540
            
                
                    
                        /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gODAK/9sAQwAGBAUGBQQ
--------------------------------------
14168 [main] INFO
org.apache.cxf.services.MagentoService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_HandlerPort.Mage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_HandlerPortType
- Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 5
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Headers: {Cache-Control=[max-age=31536000], connection=[close],
Content-Length=[275], content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8],
Date=[Fri, 17 Aug 2012 12:52:16 GMT], Expires=[Sat, 17 Aug 2013
12:52:16 GMT], Server=[Apache], Vary=[Accept-Encoding]}
Payload: 

    
        
            102
            Ungültiger Bildtyp.
        
    


--------------------------------------
```

Here is a trace:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: unsupported imagetype
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)
    at $Proxy28.catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate(Unknown Source)
    at at.myproject.soap.service.product.media.ProductAttributeMediaServiceImpl.create(ProductAttributeMediaServiceImpl.java:61)
    at at.myproject.magento.service.sync.product.ProductSyncServiceImpl.updateProduct(ProductSyncServiceImpl.java:275)
    at at.myproject.magento.service.sync.product.ProductSyncServiceImpl.updateProducts(ProductSyncServiceImpl.java:185)
    at at.myproject.magento.service.sync.product.ProductSyncServiceImpl.syncronize(ProductSyncServiceImpl.java:145)
    at at.myproject.magento.scheduler.jobs.ProductSyncJob.execute(ProductSyncJob.java:21)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Ungültiger Bildtyp.
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1656)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1521)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1429)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:659)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Any idea which part of the JDK causes the failure?

Comment: Finally i got the format of this post right!

Comment: In case you were wondering: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: It is terrible. It won't work to include the request and response including its tags to this post

Comment: I updated the post. Meanwhile I tried to run my app on oracle jdk 7 with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this issue by adding those libraries to my pom,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

, after consulting the FAQs of [Apache's CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-CanCXFrunwithJDK1.6%3F).

I ran my integration test with use of OS X's latest jdk 6 and the new openjdk7 and oracle jdk7 .